# Fill in the 3 letter blanks

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, no-computers

Please fill in the 3 letter blanks in the following numbered list

1  ---

2  CAD

3  ---

4  CNY

5  ---

6  AUD

7  ---

8  ARS

9  ---

10 ---

Please no computers/internet. A complete list would be great, but if you guess the logic that will be great also.

Comment: I have two feelings: a) this is something to do with the periodic table; b) this is going to be too difficult without the Internet, some kind of hint, or both.

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, I think the `no-computers` tag is unreasonable.  I'd suggest you look through the [highest rated no-computer questions](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-computers?sort=votes&pageSize=50) to better understand it's use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> 1 RUB (Russia)
> 2 CAD (Canada)
> 3 USD (U.S.A.)
> 4 CNY (China)
> 5 BRL (Brazil)
> 6 AUD (Australia)
> 7 INR (India)
> 8 ARS (Argentina)
> 9 KZT (Kazakhstan)
> 10 DZD (Algeria)

Because

> Currency codes of countries based on the countries' physical size (i.e. land area). That is, currency codes of the first 10 largest countries in ascending order.

Comment: I'd place BTC on the top of the list, it's universal...

Comment: AeJey  You knew the order of the countries by heart. That is great

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar Yes. I know upto 20. But I didn't remember the currency codes of Kazakhstan and Algeria and googled it. :P